# hexdump vs actual file contents

Tags: linux, php, hexdump

When I do `hexdump filename.txt` I get the following as output:

```
00000000 ac5a 5afb c08d 5d15 26d0 2491 e8c9 8917
00000010
```

When I do `<?= bin2hex(file_get_contents('filename.txt')); ?>` I get this:

```
5aacfb5a8dc0155dd0269124c9e81789
```

So why is hexdump suggesting the contents should be `ac5a5afbc08d5d1526d02491e8c98917` when PHP is suggesting they ought to be `5aacfb5a8dc0155dd0269124c9e81789`? Am I just not interpreting the output of hexdump correctly?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The difference is [big-endian vs. little-endian order](http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/Data/endian.html).

Start with the first four bytes of hexdump output:  `ac5a 5afb`.  Now switch the byte order to get:

```
5aac fb5a
```

Compare this with the PHP output:

```
5aac fb5a
```

They match.

By default, BSD `hexdump` displays output based on the machine's endianness.  If you don't want that, you can specify the `-C` option to get output byte-by-byte rather word-by-word:

```
$ hexdump filename.txt 
0000000 ac5a 5afb c08d 5d15 26d0 2491 e8c9 8917
0000010
$ hexdump -C filename.txt 
00000000  5a ac fb 5a 8d c0 15 5d  d0 26 91 24 c9 e8 17 89  |Z..Z...].&.$....|
00000010
```

Comment: To add a bit: hexdump is showing the data interpreted as sixteen-bit words. bin2hex is showing one byte at a time, as would be appropriate for ASCII characters or similar. On x86 and x64 (and other little-endian CPUs), the first byte of a multi-byte integer contains the least significant bits. So if the first thing in your file was a 16-bit integer containing the value 1, displaying it as bytes would show 01 00 , but displaying it as a 16-bit word would show 0001 (natural reading order, LSB on the right, as we do in everyday use of decimal numbers). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness

Comment: To add on @JamieHanrahan's comment, read: "and all other little-endian CPUs", as this is the very point of the endianness.